# foreach select option error retrieve data horizontal

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem when I retrieve data from database the result is

How to retrieve the data normally?

This is my codes..

```
$wewqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT itemname from table_item ");
$wewqry->execute();
$wewqry->bind_result($itemname);
$wewqry->store_result();

while ($wewqry->fetch()){
    $table = array("itemname" => $itemname);
    foreach ($table as $t => $w){
        echo '<select name="itemname">';
        echo "<option>$w</option>";
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is _horizonal_?

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new `<select>` each time through the loop, do it once outside the loop:

```
echo '<select name="itemname">';
while ($wewqry->fetch()) {
    echo "<option>$itemname</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

You also don't need to make an array for each row you fetch. Just insert the result variable directly into the `echo` statement.